# Django rest framework returning 405 for post methods after deploying

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a API using Django rest framework. In my local, everything is fine. I'm also using swagger to document my API and I can see my post and get methods at swagger.

The problem is, when I deploy my code to the server I get 405 code for my post methods and can't see post methods on swagger. They just disappear.

Here is my api:

Views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from api.models import Clinic
from api.serializers import ClinicSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view



class ClinicList(APIView):
    """
    List all clinics
    """
    def get(self, request, format = None):
        clinics = Clinic.objects.all()
        serializer = ClinicSerializer(clinics, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    """
    Save new clinic
    """
    def post(self, request, format = None):
        serializer = ClinicSerializer(data=request.data)
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

solution urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
]
```

api.urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Clinic/$', views.ClinicList.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

why am I getting 405 for post methods?

Comment: 405 usually means you are `POST`ing to the wrong url.

Comment: @KevinBrown i have only one url which is "/Clinic/" and it's returning 405 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed when server is restarted. It seems nothing is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
Import only your ClinicList as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("clinic", ClinicList.as_view()),
]
```